# How to use trained data model to make predictions about the future? Python, SKlearn

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, prediction

I'm learning how to use machine learning with SKlearn right now. I have my CLF, I am happy with the results I am getting from the training, but I can't figure out how to use it to predict the future now. I can predict up until today but I want to extend my predictions like a week into the future.

Here is my code I am working with ::

```
style.use('ggplot')

df = quandl.get("the_data")
df['PCT_change'] = (df['Close'] - df['Open']) / df['Open'] * 100.0
df['HL_PCT'] = (df['High'] - df['Low']) / df['Close'] * 100.0

df = df[['Close', 'HL_PCT', 'PCT_change', 'Volume']]
forecast_col = 'Close'
df.fillna(value=-99999, inplace=True)
forecast_out = int(math.ceil(0.01 * len(df)))

df['label'] = df[forecast_col].shift(-forecast_out)

X = np.array(df.drop(['label'], 1))
X = preprocessing.scale(X)
X_lately = X[-forecast_out:]
X = X[:-forecast_out]

df.dropna(inplace=True)

y = np.array(df['label'])

X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = cross_validation.train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.2)


# clf = LinearRegression(n_jobs=-1)
# clf.fit(X_train, y_train)

pickle_in = open('the_pickle.pickle','rb')
clf = pickle.load(pickle_in)
confidence = clf.score(X_test, y_test)
print('confidence: ', confidence)

print('HERE IS X_LATELY :::::: ', X_lately)

# forecast_set = clf.predict(X_lately)
forecast_set = clf.predict(X_lately)

df['Forecast'] = np.nan
last_date = df.iloc[-1].name
last_unix = last_date.timestamp()
one_day = 86400
next_unix = last_unix + one_day

for i in forecast_set:
    next_date = datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(next_unix)
    next_unix += 86400
    df.loc[next_date] = [np.nan for _ in range(len(df.columns) - 1)] + [i]

with open('the_pickle.pickle', 'wb') as f:
    pickle.dump(clf, f)


df['Close'].plot()
df['Forecast'].plot()
plt.legend(loc=4)
plt.xlabel('Date')
plt.ylabel('Price')
plt.show()
```

Any tips??

Comment: `forecast_out = int(math.ceil(0.01 * len(df)))` what's this line do?

Comment: It defines which part of the data I'm grabbing for my prediction. Basically, it is taking 1% of the data I'm grabbing and using that to test itself, as seen later in the code where `X_lately` is initialized as `X[-forecast_out:]`.

Comment: so, despite what the latest ML blog post says, you can't use ML to predict the future.  Your best bet is to try to capture all periodic varation, and train "today" predictions using "7-day-old" data.

Comment: I'm not sure what you think you are currently predicting? Your label here is shifted by that `forecast_out` number, so for each date you are predicting the close price that number of days into the future.